# Ways to login to multiple bot accounts with one script?

Tags: discord.js

The ways I've tried.
Loop through tokens, this is fine but not much room to customise what bot does what. Example having each bot type in a specific channel, with this I've realised the bots type in the same location right after each other.

```
const auth = require('./tokens.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

for (const token of auth.Tokens) {
    const client = new Discord.Client()
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('I am ready !')
        console.log(client.user.id)
    })
    client.login(token)
}
```

Also by creating multiple instances of a discord.client

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client1 = new Discord.Client();
const client2 = new Discord.Client();
ect...

client1.once('ready',() => {
})
client1.on('message', async(message) => {

})

client2.once('ready',() => {
})
client2.on('message', async(message) => {

})

client1.login(CONFIG.Token1);
client2.login(CONFIG.Token2);
```

I am just wondering if there is other ways of doing this, lets say I have 5-6 bots and I do the 2nd method the code will get quite long depending on what i want to add into it.
I did think about adding a loop something like this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < token.length; i++)
```

And having a channel id linked to a specific number as the i++ is increasing it. So each bot would get its own number and channel id, but I'm not sure if that's even a thing that would work or if it would be good enough to use.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thank you for reading.

Comment: If you're worried about code getting too long, then you can separate out each bot code into a different file. Then in your index.js you'll do a require on each of those files.

Comment: If the functions you passed into client.on are largely similar across bots, then you can separate it out into a defined function so reuse. Any small differences in code between bots can then be figured out by using client.user.id and switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second method:

> creating multiple instances of a `discord.client`
> Would be the best way to do it.

The easiest way to give the bots specific channels is to change their discord permissions and physically assigning them the channels.

Another way could be something like:

```js
client.channelID = <ID of channel you want the bot in>
client2.channelID = <ID of channel you want the bot in>

// ... code

client.on('message', message => {
   if (message channel.id !== client.channelID) return;
   // ...
```

Comment: What I done for the second methods for each discord client I made I added the discord id into the client.on function of each client. I was hoping I could put the bots in 1 loop somehow with individual channel ids to read/send messages the example you showed is similar to my 2nd method to apart from you didn't add client2.on

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run multiple bots from the same script using this code:

```js
const auth = ['TOKEN1', 'TOKEN2']
const Discord = require('discord.js')

for (const token of auth) {
    const client = new Discord.Client()
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('I am ready !')
        console.log(client.user.id)
    });
    client.on('message', (msg) => {
        if (msg.content === '!ping') {msg.reply('pong!')}
    });
    client.login(token);
}
```